# CodeIgniter Error - Undefined property: CI_Input::$post

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and am trying to use the conditional below to determine whether or not the form has been submitted, and then display a certain view if it has. I got the error in the title for some reason and have been troubleshooting the problem for more than half and hour. Does anybody know how I might go about solving this problem? Thanks!

```
if($this->input->post->lastName){

    // load view if form was submitted

} else {

    // load other view

}
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
if($this->input->post('lastName')){

    // load view if form was submitted

} else {

    // load other view

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

Jayrox answer is correct, but you should be thinking of using the
Form Validation class.

As stated in the Form Validation manual:

> Before explaining CodeIgniter's
>   approach to data validation, let's
>   describe the ideal scenario:
>
> 1. A form is displayed.
> 2. You fill it in and submit it.
> 3. If you submitted something invalid, or perhaps missed a required
>      item, the form is redisplayed
>      containing your data along with an
>      error message describing the problem.
> 4. This process continues until you have submitted a valid form.
>
> On the receiving end, the script must:
>
> 1. Check for required data.
> 2. Verify that the data is of the correct type, and meets the correct
>      criteria. For example, if a username
>      is submitted it must be validated to
>      contain only permitted characters. It
>      must be of a minimum length, and not
>      exceed a maximum length. The username
>      can't be someone else's existing
>      username, or perhaps even a reserved
>      word. Etc.
> 3. Sanitize the data for security.
> 4. Pre-format the data if needed (Does the data need to be trimmed?
>      HTML encoded? Etc.)
> 5. Prep the data for insertion in the database.
>
> Although there is nothing terribly
>   complex about the above process, it
>   usually requires a significant amount
>   of code, and to display error
>   messages, various control structures
>   are usually placed within the form
>   HTML. Form validation, while simple to
>   create, is generally very messy and
>   tedious to implement.

Cheers